# Enumerable.Where() not possible on IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have an XmlNodeList and want to call the .Where() to get a filtered Node-List. But this doesn't work. Now I'm wondering, why sometimes the .Where() works and sometimes not. How could I get this code running with the .Where() ?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(Xml);
var oTestNodes = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Where((item) => item.Name = "TestNode");
```

To show what I mean, this is the query expression that would do the same:

```
var oTestNodes = from XmlNode oNode in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes
                 where oNode.Name = "TestNode"
                 select oNode;
```

Comment: Don't just say "I'm not searching for this" - tell us *why* you want to reject those options. Also, it's not clear why you're putting those query expressions in brackets...

Comment: This is not valid c# code. Check your compiler errors first.

Comment: Also note that I think you mean "query expression" when you say "Linq solution" - calling the `Where` method directly is still using LINQ, IMO...

Comment: There is no technical difference between what you call LINQ-solution and what you want (as both are LINQ-expressions). The former is only another syntax (so-called query-syntax), but both are LINQ.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I reject those options because I already know how to use them. I was just wondering why sometimes the .Where can be used and sometimes not.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to explain that. Questions of "I know X will work but I don't want to use it" with no explanation are very frustrating - if we don't know why a particular solution has been rejected, we can't tell whether another solution will be rejected.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks for the feedback. I edited the question to make it more clear why I'm asking. Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most LINQ to Objects methods work on the generic `IEnumerable<T>` type, rather than `IEnumerable`. Unfortunately, `XmlNodeList` only implements `IEnumerable`.

It sounds like you're just looking for [`Cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406), which is what the query expression with the explicit range variable type uses (and hence why the query expressions compile):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(Xml);
var oTestNodes = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes
                    .Cast<XmlNode>()
                    .Where(item => item.Name = 'TestNode');
```

I'd personally recommend using LINQ to XML instead of `XmlDocument` if you possibly can though - it's a much nicer API.

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was searching for :) And thanks for the hint "LINQ to XML"